# What is the minimum number of players you can run Eternal Lies for with little/no adapation?

Tags: trail-of-cthulhu

I am considering running the Eternal Lies campaign for Trail of Cthulhu. However, I might only have three players and am concerned that this might be an issue. Having looked at the campaign I cannot see where it states a minimum number of players, and as this would be my first time running Trail of Cthulhu, I do not know what would and would not work.

So, my question is - What is the minimum number of players you can run Eternal Lies for without having to make significant changes to the written material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one of the writers of *Eternal Lies*, Will Hindmarch, it can be run with 3, but you'll want to start with fewer enemies in each of the actions scenes and "call in reinforcements" as needed.

Comment: @Ahriman direct communication with Will Hindmarch via Twitter, yesterday.